# DocuSign SOAP API setup default value for a tag

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign SOAP API to create and send an envelope. I need to setup default value for the custom tabs so that the recipients do not have to enter the values during the signing process. Though, I want to give an option to the users to replace the default values.

For some reason, once I setup the default values for the tags, the recipients are not able to change those values during the signing process.

I have referred to the previous posts for the same questions and have setup the following properties to false.

```
CustomTabRequired = false    
CustomTabRequiredSpecified = false    
CustomTabLocked = false    
CustomTabLockedSpecified = false
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Thanks,

Minal

Comment: Why is this tagged with D?

Answer (score 0):

CustomTabLocked as `false` should make it editable, I tested via SOAP UI and its working fine for me, below is the snippet XML for it:

```
<ns:Tab>
                <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
                <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                <ns:XPosition>124</ns:XPosition>
                <ns:YPosition>261</ns:YPosition>
                <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                <ns:TabLabel>Text b5a8927a-4f93-4288-b280-d15023b1b834</ns:TabLabel>
                <ns:CustomTabType>Text</ns:CustomTabType>
                <ns:Value>TestValue</ns:Value>
                <ns:CustomTabLocked>false</ns:CustomTabLocked>
            </ns:Tab>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am already setting up both the properties CustomTabLocked and CustomTabLockedSpecified as false.

Comment: which SOAP method you are calling? Are you using any DS Server Template in the API Call?

Comment: No. I am not using DS template in the API call. I am using CreateAndSendEnvelope API method.

Comment: Can you please edit your qs and share your complete XML after masking your account details, I will try to run in my DS Account via SOAP UI? I would request you to also try using SOAP UI.

Comment: How do you get the complete XML request?

Comment: [Capture DS API Logs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) will guide you how to capture API logs in DocuSign.